# Access div content from JSNI native function

Tags: java, gwt, html, jsni

What I'm trying is `elem.innerHtml`, I've also tried `elem.innerText` but I'm getting an empty string as result. Could I accessing an `HTMLDivElement` content from inside a GWT JSNI function? I would like to get rid of abstruse UiBinder work arounds.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

working under the assumption that the division you want to access is in the DOM and has an id, you can use

```
Document.get().getElementById("id")
```

from java, or

```
$doc.getElementById(String)
```

from javascript :)

Answer (score 0):

[GQuery](http://code.google.com/p/gwtquery/) can help you for doing that (assuming that your div has an id equals to myDiv):

```
import static com.google.gwt.query.client.GQuery.$

...

String innerText = $("#myDiv").text();
String innerHtml = $("#myDiv").html();
```

Comment: why use a tank to kill a fly?

Comment: It could be a good idea, but I agree with Eliran. Thanks anyway!

Comment: If it's your only dom manipulation, indeed you don't need GQuery. But It can be useful for other stuff in your project.